# Postgres SQL to select the previous valid date

Tags: sql

I am studying Postgres and run into this interesting problem that I have not been able to resolve it.

Assuming a company is shipping out goods once in a few days. This is the shipping table to record how many containers it ships out:

### Branch (character); Date (date);     containers (integer)

```
New York        2014-01-01  10
New York        2014-01-02  2
New York        2014-01-05  30
New York        2014-01-07  4
Toronto     2014-01-01  5
Toronto     2014-01-03  55
Toronto     2014-01-05  50
London          2014-01-01  60
London          2014-01-07  63
London          2014-01-12  64
```

I want to have this report:

### Branch (character); Date (date); containers (integer); Previous_date; containers_of_previous_date; delta

```
New York    2014-01-01    10    NULL    NULL    NULL
New York    2014-01-02    2    2014-01-01    10    -8
New York    2014-01-05    30    2014-01-02    2    28
New York    2014-01-07    4    2014-01-05    30    -26
Toronto    2014-01-01    5    NULL      NULL    NULL
Toronto    2014-01-03    55    2014-01-01    5    50
Toronto    2014-01-05    50    2014-01-03    55    -5
London     2014-01-01    60    NULL    NULL    NULL
London    2014-01-07    63    2014-01-01    60    3
London    2014-01-12    64    2014-01-07    63    1
```

I use this:

```
Select a.*, b.*, (a.containers – b.containers) delta
From shipping a
Join shipping b 
ON 
b.date=(select date from shipping where date<a.date order by date desc limit 1)
```

This works when the table is small. If the table grows to 100,000 records, this query is slow. I wonder if your guys have more efficient way.

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `lag()` function!

```
Select s.Branch, s.Date, s.containers,
       lag(s.Date) over (partition by branch order by date) as prev_Date,
       lag(s.containers) over (partition by branch order by date) as prev_Containers
from shipping s;
```